# HAXM installation fails claiming VT-X not present

Tags: android-studio, emulation, haxm

I'm having difficulties trying to install HAXM for my emulator in Android Studio. I have an hp2000 notebook; I updated Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 Pro to activate the Hyper-V feature and I even went to system settings to enable virtualization, but am still getting "This computer does not support Intel virtualization (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."

My Android Studio SDK manager is showing that it's installed.

Answer (score 5):

This procedure worked perfectly for me. Hope this helps.

1. F10 (Computer Set Up) - BIOS - Security -System Security -Enter -   Virtual Technology (VTX)-Enable-FileSave and Exit
2. Goto sdk Folder: F:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
   Run intelhaxm-android.exe
3. You should be seeing a dialog box which quotes, "Completed Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Set Up Wizard. Click the Finish Button to exit the wizard"

Once this works, open android studio, and try running the emulator. You should be seeing "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode"

Comment: I my checked my bios and virtual technology is enabled, HAXM wizard isnt still working. could it be my processor?

Answer (score 2):

After enabling the virtulization in-bios do hard restarting via power button solved my problem:).  I read in intel blog to do so. So try this option it may help:)

Answer (score 0):

You must have an Intel processor that supports virutalization and ND bit on. You can check http://ark.intel.com to tell.
to set ND bit you can use         bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
to set virtualization properly once enabled in BIOS you can type 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
If you're using Avast 
 disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under Settings > Troubleshooting) 
Get the download from 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: i have a AMD E-300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics processor. does that make a difference.

Comment: You MUST have an Intel processor and one that supports VT and ND bit.

Comment: All Intel CPUs can be looked up at ark.intel.com by CPU model number and will say yes or no for each capability including these 2.

Answer (score 0):

well, i  turned off hyper-v on optional windows components (saim's suggestion).  enabled virt in bios.  then i went to find the haxm reinstall, and only found this file, C:\Users\ich\AppData\Local\Temp\intel\HAXM\1.1.1\silent\hax64.msi (i have a 64 bit box), ran it, and android studio 1.5.1 is happy.  windows 10.  hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Intel Virtualization Technology from BIOS or if you dont have installed  Emulator Acceleator(HAXM) you should install.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off your PC and turn it back on, then instantly hit F10 or the ESC button (whichever works for you) - it will enter you into the BIOS
2. Use the arrow keys to enter into System Security
3. Ensure VIRTUAL TECHNOLOGY VTX is checked, then hit F10 to save, and reboot your computer
4. Now press the Windows key on your keyboard and just type Hyper-V; then click on the top appearing result
5. Uncheck Hyper-V from there
6. Now go to the path where you have saved your sdk folder - by default it is saved in C:\
7. Go to C:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\ and run Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager, then run intelhaxm-android.exe
8. If it shows a dialog box which quotes, "Completed Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Set Up Wizard", click the finish button to exit the wizard
9. Open Android Studio again, run your app, and if it doesn't show your virtual devices then click on the small refresh button on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. It worked out that I hadn't got the HAXM-Installer installed on my PC.

To do this go to: Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (Tab) -> Check the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) option then click apply (**As shown in the image below**).

[Android SDK Manager (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zAtv.png)