# Android App doesn't run in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to run my app in `Android Studio`'s emulator, all that shows up is a blank dark screen. This is the message:

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

Comment: Emulator take some time to start when you initially start using Android Studio. You might face some issues during the first few days. Kindly visit this post. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911176/haxm-installation-fails-claiming-vt-x-not-present/28949355#28949355)

Comment: You should use Genymotion, it is the best emulator, i recommend.